# Virtual directories in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, webserver, web-development-server

I have a domain like: `clients.mydomain.com` which I want to be able to run multiple websites under as a quick demonstration area for clients, so I might have:

```
clients.mydomain.com/client1
clients.mydomain.com/client2
```

The problem is when we develop websites we always like to use root relative links, so referencing a CSS file would look like `href="/css/myfile.css"`. When a HTML file is dropped into the client1 or client2 folder, it believes the website root to be clients.mydomain.com and therefore it cant find the css files - the links are broken.

Is there a way of setting up a virtual directory which is set as the root? Otherwise we will have to setup a sub-domain for each client which is a real pain and untidy on the server.

Answer (score 0):

URL Rewrite

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this would be achievable using IIS Rewrite. This would still mean that the web.config in the root would be executed whereas I want the web.config in the client1 folder to be executed if the user has typed in clients.mydomain.com/client1

Comment: Set up the physical hierarchy in IIS Manager like you wished, and then use URL Rewrite module to map the desired URL (virtual hierarchy) to this physical one.